# Finding the Maclaurin series of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to find the Maclaurin series of the following function:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}}$$

I have tried looking at writing out the first few terms with no success, and I have also looked at using a simpler comparable function, like $\frac{1}{1-x}$ . Thanks for any help or direction!

Comment: use the binomial expansion

Comment: Right, @JimmySabater, but I think you want to factor out $1/\sqrt3$ so that what’s under the radical becomes $1-x/3$, more suitable to use of Binomial Expansion.

Comment: see below.......

Answer (score 2):

notice that

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3(1-x/3)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{x}{3} \right)^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {-1/2 \choose n} (-1)^n (x/3)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three ways to solve your problem.

The first and the best would be Newton's binomial expansion.

The second would be just keep taking derivatives and find few terms to come up with pattern.

The third method and probably the most time consuming is to notice that your function is the square root of $\frac {1}{3-x}$.

So if you find the square of your Laurent series  you get the Laurent series of $\frac {1}{3-x}$

That way you can find the coefficient your series one by one.